# Inequality operator not allowed for this type: wrapperOrder(wrapper class)

Tags: apex

I have a wrapper class variable as -

```
map<String,wrapperOrder> workOrderNameToSumMap = new map<String,wrapperOrder>();
```

When i am trying to assign to a string variable i am getting error

```
String maxKey = workOrderNameToSumMap.isEmpty()?null:new List<String>(workOrderNameToSumMap.keyset())[0];
    for(String s1:workOrderNameToSumMap.keySet()) {

        maxKey = workOrderNameToSumMap.get(s1)>workOrderNameToSumMap.get(maxKey)?s1:maxKey;

    }
```

Error -

> Inequality operator not allowed for this type: wrapperOrder

Comment: What do you expect from this line? `workOrderNameToSumMap.get(s1)>workOrderNameToSumMap.get(maxKey)` It tries to compare two wrapper instance is it?

Answer (score 1):

That error is spot on, and says exactly what the issue is.

On the line in question

```
maxKey = workOrderNameToSumMap.get(s1) > workOrderNameToSumMap.get(maxKey)?s1:maxKey;
```

The statements `workOrderNameToSumMap.get(s1)` and `workOrderNameToSumMap.get(maxKey)` evaluate to instances of your `wrapperOrder` class.

As far as I know, there's no way to make the greater than / less than operators work on classes (I thought the comparable interface might've done it, but it looks like that's just for list sorting).

You didn't provide the details of `wrapperOrder`, but you want to be doing your comparison based on one of the attributes of that class.

Assuming that it's something like `keyVal`, your code should look something like this:

```
String maxKey = workOrderNameToSumMap.isEmpty()?null:new List<String>(workOrderNameToSumMap.keyset())[0];
for(String s1:workOrderNameToSumMap.keySet()) {
    maxKey = workOrderNameToSumMap.get(s1).keyVal > workOrderNameToSumMap.get(maxKey).keyVal ? s1.keyVal : maxKey.keyVal;
}
```

You also need to be careful when doing string comparison, `value2` is greater than `value19`, and `value120` is less than `value17` (because of lexicographic ordering). It'd be much better to compare `Integers` or `Decimals` if possible (Dates and DateTimes are ok as well).

You can see this effect more clearly if you run the following code:

```
List<String> testList = new List<String>();
for(Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++){
    testList.add('test' + i);
}

testList.sort();

Integer i = 0;
for(String s :testList){
    system.debug('#' + i + ': ' + s);
    i++;
}
```